# Why won't this if statement comparing WPF ImageSources be executed?

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, wpf-controls

I'm checking that an image matches the image source that I want, which will then instantiate a class "Queen". To do this, I am iterating through a list of objects, "nodes", which has a method, getType(), which returns an image. I am checking each of the images in this colony.getNodes() list.

I am 100% sure that at least one of the images matches "H:\Year 13\Computing\Ant Simulation\QueenRoom.png" as I have checked using breakpoints. So why won't it ever enter my if statement.

I have also tried instead of comparing colony.getNodes()[i].getType().Source to a new instance of BitmapImage, creating a BitmapImage variable before the for loop, however this didn't help.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < colony.getNodes().Count; i++)
        {
            if (colony.getNodes()[i].getType().Source == new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"H:\Year 13\Computing\Ant Simulation\LarvaRoom.png")))
            {
                nurseryFood.Add(colony.getNodes()[i].getLocation(), 0);
            }
            if (colony.getNodes()[i].getType().Source == new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"H:\Year 13\Computing\Ant Simulation\QueenRoom.png")))
            {
                queen = new Queen(colony.getNodes()[i].getLocation(), colony.getNodes()[i].getType().Margin);
            }
        }
```

I also have another if statement which has exactly the same problem. Testing using breakpoints, the if statements are never entered. How can I make this work?

Comment: `...Source == new BitmapImage()` presumably does a **reference** comparison, which obviously is false because these are two different instances. I don't think an actual _image_ really is a good key to identify an object, so I'd suggest to rethink your data design.

Comment: Besides that, just compare the Uris: `((BitmapImage)colony.getNodes()[i].getType().Source).UriSource == new Uri(@"H:\Year 13\Computing\Ant Simulation\LarvaRoom.png")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @RenéVogt said, the reason why your if are never entered is because `Source == new BitmapImage()` is doing a reference comparison. Since you are working on two different instances, it will always return false.

If you want your ifs to work, you could check the .UriSource of your Node against the new BitmapImages' (assuming that your node is also a BitmapImage).

For instance :

```
if (new Uri(Convert.ToString(colony.getNodes()[i].getType().Source)) == new Uri(@"H:\Year 13\Computing\Ant Simulation\LarvaRoom.png"))
```

Comment: "System.Windows.Controls.Image" does not contain a definition for "UriSource"

Comment: @DennisBuntwin My answer assumed that your node was a BitmapImage. But the idea stay the same for an Image. Namely : check if the BitmapImage is using the same source as your Node.
But, I would advise you to find another way to check if your images are the same. With your current setup there is a tons of problems that could arise.